# Can I restore an itunes backup from ios 12 onto ios 15?

Tags: ios

Lets say I have a backup made on itunes while on ios 12.4.1, same phone is then updated to ios 15.7.8.
Will it now accept that old backup? If yes, will things get messy on the phone? conflicts, lost data ecc.

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Comment: forgot to add that i cant just try it myself at the moment for a few reasons

Answer (score 1):

All we can really say is, you shouldn't have any issues, as the OS isn't in the backup, only your data & links to your apps [which will have to come down OTA from the App Store, so long as they still exist.]

However, you also have no choice but to try it.
You can't get iOS12 back on there.

One further note - don't wait to do this. Restoring from a backup will overwrite the entire device; all data introduced since that backup, so anything new will be gone. There is no way to merge backups.